# Geometry theorem prover with support for square intersection

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, z3, theorem-proving

I am trying to automatically prove/disprove some theorems in geometry, related to squares, such as "For every 3 collections of 7 disjoint squares, it is possible to select 1 square from each collection such that the 3 representatives are interior disjoint?".

I tried to use [OpenGeoProver](http://code.google.com/p/open-geo-prover/) and came up with the following description of a square:

```
    <!-- define a 'free' point - the south-western corner of the square: -->
    <pfree       label="square1southwest"/>

    <!-- define a line that is parallel to the x axis and goes throught that point - the southern boundary: -->
    <lparallel   label="square1south" point="square1southwest" baseline="xaxis" />

    <!-- define a random point on the southern line, which will be the south-eastern corner: -->
    <prandline   label="square1southeast" line="square1south" />

    <!-- rotate the south-eastern corner 90 degrees around the south-western corner, to create the north-western corner: -->
    <protated    label="square1northwest" origpt="square1southeast" center="square1southwest" angmeasure="-90"/>

    <!-- translate the north-western corner by the vector between the two southern corners, to create the north-eastern corner of the square: -->
    <ptranslated label="square1northeast" origpt="square1northwest" point1="square1southwest" point2="square1southeast"/>
```

This is where I am stuck: how to define the simple statement "square A and square B intersect"?

How can this problem be approached in Z3?

Comment: I think this is off-topic on SE, because it is a [“shopping recommendation”](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics

Comment: I " describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it". Can it be reopened?

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to disprove your theorem using [MiniZinc](http://www.minizinc.org/):

```
int: noOfCollections = 3;
int: noOfDisjoints = 7;
int: noOfSquares = noOfCollections * noOfDisjoints;
set of int: Squares = 1..noOfSquares;
int: maxDim = 10000;  %  somewhat arbitrary limit!
int: maxLeft = maxDim;
int: maxRight = maxDim;
int: maxTop = maxDim;
int: maxBottom = maxDim;
int: maxHeight = maxBottom - 1;
int: maxWidth = maxRight - 1;

array[Squares] of var 1..maxLeft: Left;
array[Squares] of var 1..maxTop: Top;
array[Squares] of var 1..maxHeight: Height;
array[Squares] of var 1..maxWidth: Width;
array[Squares] of var bool: Representative;
array[Squares] of 1..noOfCollections: 
      Collection = [1 + (s mod noOfCollections) | s in Squares];

%  Squares must fit in the overall frame
constraint
    forall(s in Squares)(
        (Left[s] + Width[s] - 1 <= maxRight) /\
        (Top[s] + Height[s] - 1 <= maxBottom)
    );

predicate disjoint(var int: s1, var int: s2) =
    (Left[s1] + Width[s1] - 1 < Left[s2]) \/
    (Left[s2] + Width[s2] - 1 < Left[s1]) \/
    (Top[s1] + Height[s1] - 1 < Top[s2]) \/
    (Top[s2] + Height[s2] - 1 < Top[s1]);

%  Squares in a collection must be disjoint
constraint
    forall(s1 in Squares, s2 in Squares 
           where (s1 > s2) /\ (Collection[s1] == Collection[s2]))(
        disjoint(s1, s2)
    );

%   Exactly one Representative per Collection
constraint
    1 == sum(c in 1..noOfCollections, s in Squares 
             where c == 1 + (s mod noOfCollections))
           (bool2int(Representative[s]));

%   Is it possible to select 1 square from each collection such 
%   that the 3 representatives are interior disjoint?
constraint
    forall(s1 in Squares, s2 in Squares, s3 in Squares
           where (Collection[s1] == 1) /\
                 (Collection[s2] == 2) /\
                 (Collection[s3] == 3))(
        disjoint(s1, s2) /\
        disjoint(s1, s3) /\
        disjoint(s2, s3) /\
        Representative[s1] /\
        Representative[s2] /\
        Representative[s3]
    );

solve satisfy;
```

MiniZinc comes up with "UNSAT" after 45ms.

Answer (score 0):

am I the only one that see this as algorithmic problem ?

- yes the title and start of question is a bit confusing but
- as I understand the question is (or should be) how to achieve prove of geometry statement.
- some re-edit/re-tag will be good for it I think

I would do it like this (will not use any language or framework because it is not relevant):

1.dataset definition

- sum/size/count for geometric entities used for theorem (points,lines,rects,...)
- sum of all conditions/constrains for input data

2.dataset generation

- can be random + throw away invalid entities (which do not match 1)
- or you can generate all valid possibilities within some accuracy for position/size...
- but that is really nasty because of time and space complexity
- this is the hard part
- you must choose between performance/relevance
- I am afraid that this task cannot be automated with satisfactory performance
- instead you have to write some generation script for each theorem

3.theorem statement

- this is the easiest part
- just check if the theorem is valid for current dataset
- if not theorem is not valid
- if the dataset is random use big enough count of tests ...

**You got problem with statement "square A and square B intersect"**

- I assume you stated it after dataset is generated
- this is just another condition for bullet 1
- so your dataset generator must generate intersecting A,B squares
- A - generate as is
- put B - start point inside A (randomly or in the middle or whatever)
- another option is select only intersecting squares from dataset
- go through all i=1..N squares (A)
- then go through i+1..N squares and if the two are intersecting then it is your B square

hope I am not too far away from what you wanted to do ...

Comment: Your suggestion of building a random dataset and check if the theorem holds is actually very good for dis-proving theorems. I have used it many times to find non-trivial counter-examples to theorems. But, in order to prove a theorem, you have to check all possible cases, which might be impossible because the number of different squares is infinite...

Comment: yep ... therefore you can only simulate infinite possibilities by some accuracy grid for sizes and positions ... or do some nasty heuristics of the theorem constrains and generate only cases which matter